# Allow user to enable / disable options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

Im working on a wordpress plugin that just displays a simple div on all pages. I have the code that creates it, makes it a shortcode and then displays on every page.

I would like to add a checkbox in the admin settings that enables the user to turn this on/off. Eg is they unchecked the box, the div wouldn't show on the pages.

My code:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'webdev_load');

//Main PLugin Page
function plugin_home(){

       // This is the admin page for the plugin. A checkbox should go here

}

function webdev_create(){  

return '<span style="position:fixed;bottom:0;left:0;padding:10px;background-color:red;color:white;z-index:9999">- WEBDEV2 -</span>';
}

// Loads the webdev banner on every page automatically
function webdev_load(){

        echo do_shortcode('[webdev]');

}

add_shortcode('webdev', 'webdev_create');
```

I know that I need this code:

```
  add_settings_field("demo-checkbox", "Demo Checkbox", "demo_checkbox_display", "demo", "section");  
    register_setting("section", "demo-checkbox");
<?php checked(1, get_option('demo-checkbox'), true); ?> />
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to integrate this checkbox, why have you failed? Or do you expect us to write that code for you?

Comment: @Connum Iv added some stuff I know I need, but dont know where to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

see examples on this page https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages or if you don't want to mess up with code, you can use advanced custom fields option pages - it's pretty simple - https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/options-page/